# is there a way to making v-for value dynamic?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a dynamic component and I wanted to iterate various obejcts from it, but my code doesn't work and how can I make the activeQuestion value in v-for dynamic? thanks for help

```
<component  v-for="data in activeQuestion" 
:is="data.activeComponent" 
:key="data"
:question="data.question"
:correctAnswerEnglish="data.correctAnswer">
</component>


 data() {
   return {

    activeQuestion: this.test1.level1,

      
    test1: {
        question1: [
             {
        question: 'this is the question',
        correctAnswer: ['hello', 'world'],
        activeComponent: 'Writing',
             }
        ],

       question2: [.......]


   }
  }
```

Comment: How are you changing the `activeQuestion` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a small work around this. Check out this link for the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-w5kvmg)

```
// App.vue
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <button @click="changeQuestion">Toggle Question</button>
        <div v-if="test1[activeQuestion]">
            <component v-for="data in test1[activeQuestion]" :is="data.activeComponent" :key="data" :question="data.question" :answer="data.correctAnswer">
            </component>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import First from './components/First'
import Second from './components/Second'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    First, // You can register them globally if you want
    Second
  },
  data() {
    return {
      activeQuestion: 'question1',
      test1: {}
    }
  },
 mounted() {
   callingAPI().then(data => {
    // assuming data will be in this format
    data = {
      question1: [
          {
            question: 'This is the first question',
            correctAnswer: ['hello', 'world'],
            activeComponent: 'First',
          },
          {
            question: 'This is the second question',
            correctAnswer: ['hello', 'world'],
            activeComponent: 'First',
          }
        ],
        question2: [
          {
            question: 'this is the first question',
            correctAnswer: ['test', 'test 2'],
            activeComponent: 'Second',
          },
          {
              question: 'This is the second question',
              correctAnswer: ['hello', 'world'],
              activeComponent: 'Second',
          }
        ]
    }
    this.test1 = data
   })
 },
  methods: {
    changeQuestion() {
      // Change this logic accordingly your convenience
      this.activeQuestion = this.activeQuestion === 'question1' ? 'question2' : 'question1'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```
// components/First.vue
<template>
    <div class="hello">
        <h1>First Component</h1>
        <h2>{{ question }}</h2>
        {{ answer }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
  name: 'First',
  props: {
    question: String,
    answer: String
  }
}
</script>
```

```
// ./components/Second.vue
<template>
    <div class="hello">
        <h1>Second Component</h1>
        <h2>{{ question }}</h2>
        {{ answer }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
  name: 'Second',
  props: {
    question: String,
    answer: String
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for giving your time, it was useful and how can I also make the test1 value dynamic in v-for="data in test1[activeQuestion]"  , because I might fetch data from api with value test2: { [{question1}] }....

Comment: you can use mounted/created to hook to call api and update the data. I did updated the answer with mock data check once

Answer (score 0):

You can make the dynamic v-for using computed properties/methods in Vue.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

You can check the above link where in the example you will see that they are using the computed property and then directly iterating over that property in the v-for.